When does a projection to a sub-algebra preserve positive semidefinateness
given a unital algebra over the complex field, $\mathcal{U}$, with a unital sub-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. I can define
$\rho \mapsto \rho_{\mathcal{A}} = \sum_{X\in B} Tr(X^{*} \rho) X$
where $B$ is a basis of $\mathcal{A}$ (as a vector space), $\rho \in \mathcal{U}$, and $X^{*}$ is the dual of $X$ with respect to the inner product defined by trace.
Are there any properties of $\mathcal{A}$ which can guarantee that if $\rho$ is positive semi-definate, then $\rho_{\mathcal{A}}$ is positive semi-definate.
